# Trying to output only reservations totaling over $2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, having-clause

```
SELECT 
    reservationWH.RNUM AS Reservation, 
    packageWH.PNAME AS "Package Name", 
    (COUNT(guestWH.CELL_PHONE) * packageWH.COSTPERSON) AS "Total Cost"
FROM 
    packageWH 
INNER JOIN 
    reservationWH ON packageWH.P_ID = reservationWH.P_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    guestWH ON reservationWH.RNUM = guestWH.RNUM
WHERE 
    (COUNT(guestWH.CELL_PHONE)) * packageWH.COSTPERSON > 2000
GROUP BY 
    reservationWH.RNUM
ORDER BY 
    reservationWH.RNUM ASC
```

I get this error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

Comment: Use sub-queries to store the result of group by clause and then do the required join and the required where

Comment: Hint:  `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.

Answer (score 0):

You need include having clause like below

```
    SELECT reservationWH.RNUM AS Reservation, packageWH.PNAME AS "Package Name" , 
   COUNT(guestWH.CELL_PHONE)* sum(packageWH.COSTPERSON) AS "Total Cost"
    FROM packageWH INNER JOIN reservationWH ON packageWH.P_ID=reservationWH.P_ID INNER JOIN guestWH ON reservationWH.RNUM=guestWH.RNUM
    GROUP BY reservationWH.RNUM,packageWH.PNAME
    having (COUNT(guestWH.CELL_PHONE)*sum(packageWH.COSTPERSON)) > 2000
    ORDER BY reservationWH.RNUM ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

With no access to data, nor any visibility of the wanted result, solving this is something of a guessing game. Perhaps you need to move the grouping into a subquery, and this way you can use a where clause, e.g.

```
SELECT
    reservationWH.RNUM                   AS Reservation
  , packageWH.PNAME                      AS "Package Name"
  , (g.num_cells * packageWH.COSTPERSON) AS "Total Cost"
FROM packageWH
INNER JOIN reservationWH ON packageWH.P_ID = reservationWH.P_ID
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            RNUM
          , COUNT( CELL_PHONE ) num_cells
        FROM guestWH
        GROUP BY
            RNUM
    ) g ON reservationWH.RNUM = g.RNUM
WHERE (g.num_cells * packageWH.COSTPERSON) > 2000
ORDER BY
    reservationWH.RNUM ASC
```

But, without **sample data** and **expected result** this is impossible for me to verify.

Answer (score 0):

If I assume that you want one row per reservation, then remove `PNAME` from the query.  If I further assume that `g.CELL_PHONE` is never `NULL`, then:

```
SELECT r.RNUM AS Reservation, 
       SUM(p.COSTPERSON) AS "Total Cost"
FROM packageWH p INNER JOIN 
     reservationWH
     ON p.P_ID = r.P_ID INNER JOIN 
     guestWH g
     ON r.RNUM = g.RNUM
GROUP BY r.RNUM
HAVING SUM(p.COSTPERSON) > 2000
ORDER BY r.RNUM ASC;
```

Notes:

- You want the filtering on the aggregation column in the `HAVING` clause not the `WHERE` clause.
- If you want one row per reservation, then you should be aggregating *only* by the aggregation.
- You seem to want to sum the costs per person, so `SUM()` makes more sense than `COUNT()`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of users googling error messages:

> An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

An aggregate is a grouping function such as COUNT, SUM, MAX, MIN, ...

You can find the full list here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/aggregate-functions-transact-sql

In other words, you cannot have a grouping function in your where section unless you use it in a sub-query.

```
WHERE x = (SELECT SUM(y) FORM z)
```

In the context of this question, you probably just need to use a having clause instead.

```
SELECT 
    reservationWH.RNUM AS Reservation, 
    packageWH.PNAME AS "Package Name", 
    (COUNT(guestWH.CELL_PHONE) * packageWH.COSTPERSON) AS "Total Cost"
FROM 
    packageWH 
INNER JOIN 
    reservationWH ON packageWH.P_ID = reservationWH.P_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    guestWH ON reservationWH.RNUM = guestWH.RNUM
GROUP BY 
    reservationWH.RNUM
HAVING
    (COUNT(guestWH.CELL_PHONE)) * packageWH.COSTPERSON > 2000
ORDER BY 
    reservationWH.RNUM ASC
```